# How to sum all the values from a table while using inner join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, inner-join

I have a shop database in which I'm trying to sum all the profits ever made. However, when I make the sum it just repeats the values already in the column, instead of doing the sum. I must be forgetting something because I am new to this.

My query:

```
select "date", product.id, sell_price - provider_price, sum(sell_price - provider_price)
from sellings
INNER JOIN product ON sellings.product_id = product.id
group by "date", product.id
order by sell_price - provider_price desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head you could do your subtraction as a CTE first:

```
WITH TEMP AS(
    SELECT 
        date
        ,pro.id 
        ,(sel.sell_price - pro.provider_price) as net_price
    FROM sellings sel
    INNER JOIN product pro ON pro.id = sel.product_id 
)
SELECT 
    date
    ,id
    ,sum(net_price) as sum_net_price
FROM TEMP
GROUP BY date, id
ORDER BY sum_net_price desc
```

I'm sure there's a simpler way but that's a possible solution.

Edit: In answer to your follow up question, you can also obtain the sum of the sum_net_price in a similar way:

```
        WITH TEMP AS(
        SELECT 
            date
            ,pro.id 
            ,(sel.sell_price - pro.provider_price) as net_price
        FROM sellings sel
        INNER JOIN product pro ON pro.id = sel.product_id 
    ), WITH AGG1 AS(
        SELECT 
            id
            ,sum(sum_net_price) as sum_net_price_output
        FROM TEMP
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY sum_net_price desc
)
    SELECT
        id
        ,sum_net_price_output
    FROM AGG1;
```

This will produce the final aggregated sum of net price by product_id.

Comment: well i tried what you said and it works thank you, but now i wanted to get the sum of all "sum_net_price", is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the sum_net_price?

Comment: yes i mean that

Comment: hey sorry for the late response but i was only able to check thist now. I tried your answer but ir doesn't work. First is says "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"LINE 24:     ),  WITH AGG1 AS(" and then when i eliminate the word "WITH" it says ERROR:  column "sum_net_price" does not exist.
I'm sorry but I am new to this and I can't understant what the problem is

Comment: Apologies, I made some syntactical errors there. I'll amend/fix the query later to reflect, but you can enact the following: remove the second "WITH", change the first sum from "sum(sum_net_price)" to sum(net_price) as sum_net_price. That should produce a functioning query, but I'll need to review in order to provide the output you'd want. With your CTEs in place you can then perform operations on the aggregated data.

Comment: ok i already made it work but thanks anyway